# Unable to permanently delete items from a list

Tags: python

As part of a wider class, I am attempting to delete items in a list based on their names when called.

Currently I have a code that is like the following:

```
users = [["Engineer", "Joe Blogs"], ["Scientist", "John Doe"]]
# many line of code later

def deleteName(name):

    for items in users:
        for values in items:
            if name in items:

                job = items[0]
                firstLastName = items[1]

                items.remove(job)
                items.remove(firstLastName)

                print(users)
```

at the `print(users)` point, everything works as intended. But as soon as I attempt to give back the changed list, I get the unchanged list again. I understand this is about scope, but I don't know how to solve it.

`users` is being used by other code.

Comment: If I call, `deleteName("Joe Blogs")`, I get `[[], ['Scientist', 'John Doe']]`, as expected. Please post an MCVE showing the function call, expected result, and what it actually gives.

Comment: The `for values in items:` loop isn't doing anything in this code snippet, and it wouldn't make sense for this action to be inside that loop. Can you give an example of what `name` might be (the parameter to `deleteName`) - that is, give a sample case (or several) of how you want it to work?

Comment: "give back the changed list": what do you mean by that? You don't return anything, nor do you call `deleteName`, so it's unclear what you mean by that.

Comment: lists are global anyways, this has nothing to do with scope but why are You using `.remove`? You might as well just use `.pop()`

Comment: You are not deleting the variables you call "items" but you keep an empty list. I don't think that is your intention as I read your question. if you just want to delete that whole item from users you can use `users.remove(items)` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only issue I see here is that you are not removing the the item form the users list - if you iterate through the list and count it for example the list will not shrink , so you need to remove the whole item from the list

```
  users = [["Engineer", "Joe Blogs"], ["Scientist", "John Doe"]]
    # many line of code later
    
    def deleteName(name):
    
        for items in users:
            for values in items:
                if name in items:
    
                    job = items[0]
                    firstLastName = items[1]
    
                    items.remove(job)
                    items.remove(firstLastName)
                    users.remove(items) // NB
                    print(users)
                    
    deleteName("John Doe")
    deleteName("Joe Blogs")
```

this example above works as expected - can you provide your resultant list maybe

Answer (score 0):

This works. As a note I would suggest you not to use global variables (users) inside functions, just pass them as parameters if you need them.

```py
users = [["Engineer", "Joe Blogs"], ["Scientist", "John Doe"]]
# many line of code later


def deleteName(name, users):

    for items in users:

        _, firstLastName = items
        if firstLastName == name:

            users.remove(items)


deleteName("Joe Blogs", users)
print(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting `items`, but you keep an empty list. I don't think that is your intention as I read your question. So deleting that you can use `users.remove(items)` in your code. In addition you are also looping over `values` without using `values` later, than don't use that loop.

based on your code:

```
users = [["Engineer", "Joe Blogs"], ["Scientist", "John Doe"]]
# many line of code later

def deleteName(name):

    for items in users:
        if name in items:
            users.remove(items)

deleteName("Joe Blogs")
print(users)
```

Output:

```
[["Scientist", "John Doe"]]
```

If you want to keep `users` unchanged in the process, you can use the lambda function with `filter`:

```
>> filter(lambda items: "Joe Blogs" not in items, users)
[["Scientist", "John Doe"]]
```